# Form validation for a specific numeric input (numeric range + number 0)

Tags: html, validation

I have to validate an input where the numeric input value could
 range from 110 to 150
 OR 
 could be zero.

Is there any chance I can do it with HTML5 validation I'm currently using for the other inputs? If not, what's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <input type="text" pattern="(0|1[1-4][0-9]|150)" />
```

This was the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to this using some simple javascript:

```js
function verifyNumber(){
  const inputID = this.id;
  const label = document.querySelector(`label[for="${inputID}"]`);
  if ((this.value > 110 && this.value < 150) || (this.value == 0)){
   label.style = 'display: None';
  } else {
   label.style = '';
  }
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', verifyNumber);
```

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="number" name="quantity">
<label style="display: None;" for="myInput">Please select a number between 110 and 150 or input 0</label>
```

Comment: thanks for you effort. This code works but it is not what I needed.